{How to toggle the current directory in `JFileChooser`?
I want to use the "Home" button in JFileChooser to toggle between a custom directory and the home directory.
static final File HOME = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
static final File CUSTOM = new File(HOME, ".jpilot");
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(new File("TestData", "in")) {
  void homeButtonPressed() {
    setCurrentDirectory(!getCurrentDirectory().equals(HOME) ? HOME : CUSTOM);
  }
};
fc.showOpenDialog(this);
File file = fc.getSelectedFile();

So my question is how to replace the non-existing fictional homeButtonPressed() method with a working code.
Here you see the button, I mean:

Looking for a suitable Listener, I executed the following:
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(new File("TestData/in"));
System.out.println("FileChooser="+fc.getClass());
System.out.println("FileSystemView="+fc.getFileSystemView().getClass());
for (PropertyChangeListener listener : fc.getPropertyChangeListeners())
  System.out.println("PropChListener="+listener);
for (Component component : fc.getComponents())
  System.out.println("Component="+component);
for (ComponentListener listener : fc.getComponentListeners())
  System.out.println("CompListener="+listener);
PropertyChangeListener dirListener = fc.getPropertyChangeListeners()[3];
System.out.println("dirListener="+dirListener.getClass());

It looks like the BasicDirectoryModel could be useful, but I have no idea, how to use it.
Which name should I use for fc.getPropertyChangeListeners(String propertyName)?
FileChooser=class javax.swing.JFileChooser
FileSystemView=class javax.swing.filechooser.UnixFileSystemView
PropChListener=sun.swing.FilePane[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@17b8a8df,flags=265,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=405,height=135]]
PropChListener=sun.swing.plaf.synth.SynthFileChooserUIImpl$FilterComboBoxModel@141e7727
PropChListener=sun.swing.plaf.synth.SynthFileChooserUI$SynthFCPropertyChangeListener@18d105a
PropChListener=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicDirectoryModel@5a761e8e
PropChListener=java.beans.PropertyChangeListenerProxy@46c7373a
Component=javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@2187d78a,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
Component=javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@48610c20,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
Component=sun.swing.FilePane[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@17b8a8df,flags=265,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=405,height=135]]
Component=javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.BoxLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@2209e9cc,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
dirListener=class javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicDirectoryModel

By the way, I'm using Java 21 and develop with NetBeans IDE.

The file chooser uses a modal dialog which means the code after the showOpenDialog() statement is not executed until the dialog is closed. If you want to set the current directly you need to execute that code BEFORE the showOpenDialog() statement.

I want to make sure that I understand which Home button you are referring to. Can you [edit] your question and post an image of your JFileChooser and indicate which button is the Home button? Also, what look-and-feel are you using and what platform are you on? From the code in your question, I am guessing that you are on Mac or linux.

@camickr Yes, but the dialogue must be on the screen, to press the "Home" button.

@Abra I'm working on Ubuntu Linux and design and develop the GUI with NetBeans IDE. See screen shot above.

So now I'm only looking how to place the button to a better position. - Your question was about toggling the Home button. I showed you how to access the button and change the ActionListener of the button. You could also easily toggle the Icon of the Home button to reflect the action that will occur when you click the button.

You can use the following example code to create a new custom button and add an action listener to it. The listener has code to set the required directory to choose from.
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    
    JButton btn = new JButton("Test");
    btn.addActionListener(e -> {
        System.out.println("Test button clicked...");
        fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("X:\\java\\programs"));
    });

    fc.setAccessory(btn);

Edit NOTE: Other componenets to consider are the JToggleButton and the JCheckBox, instead of a JButton. These can be added to the file chooser along with their respective listener .

Edit (16-May):
public class FileChooserDemo2 {

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        JButton customBtn = new JButton("Test");

        // new path to switch to 
        // (substitute your path string here)
        String pathStr = "X:\\apps"; 

        customBtn.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("Test button clicked...");
            fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File(pathStr));
        });

        fc.setAccessory(customBtn);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FileChooser Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton openButton = new JButton("Open...");
        openButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(frame);
        });
        frame.add(openButton);
        frame.setLocation(200, 200);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGUI());
    }
}


This code sets a big quadratic Button right of the file list pane. This looks very ugly.
How can I set the Button to another position in the line with the 2 existing buttons "Cancel" and "Open"?
Additionally it does not change the content of the file list pane. The only thing it does, is the print on the console. What is missing here?

@CoSoCo This is about a possibility that an additional button (or a check box, etc.) can be placed in the file chooser and assign a listener to it. The code doesn't do any formatting or sizing or placing of the button - this requires additional work based upon one's needs. (2) Yes, it does change the content listed in the file chooser, it reflects the directory and its files as coded in the statement fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File(your_existing_dir_path_here));.

In my attempt the statement did not change the content, listed in the file chooser.
Any idea, what I'm doing wrong?

@CoSoCo I included a simple demo program you can try. I am running using Java 17 on Windows 11 PC.

Thanks for the work. This runs fine.
Now I see, that yesterday I forgot the File.separator between System.getProperty("user.home") and my path. Yes, it was late last evening.
So now I'm only looking how to place the button to a better position.


how to replace the non-existing fictional fc.homeButtonPressed() method with a working code.

This would be a two step process:
Find the "Home" button:
JFileChooser  fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");
BasicFileChooserUI ui = (BasicFileChooserUI)fileChooser.getUI();
Action home = ui.getGoHomeAction();

Replace the ActionListener of the button with a custom ActionListener
Icon icon = UIManager.getIcon("FileChooser.homeFolderIcon");
JButton button = SwingUtils.getDescendantOfType(JButton.class, fileChooser, "Icon", icon);
button.removeActionListener( home );
button.addActionListener((e) -> System.out.println("Home Folder Clicked"));

You will need the Swing Utils class for this solution.

I don't understand, how that could help for my question.
How can I toggle the directory with that code?

@CoSoCo See edits.

Your code gave me the idea of another smart solution, see my answer. Thanks for the hint with Swing Utils.

I use Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (2024-03) on Windows 11. By default, that IDE uses Java 17.
The Home button depends on the look-and-feel. For me, only the default look-and-feel and the Nimbus look-and-feel displayed a Home button.
I looked at the code for class JFileChooser and decided that in order to change the behavior of the Home button, I needed to extend [abstract] class FileSystemView. Since I am on Windows, I discovered that I cannot extend class WindowsFileSystemView so I used that class's code as a basis for my custom FileSystemView class. Below is the code. Note that method getHomeDirectory() is the method that gets called when the Home button is activated. Hence I changed that method as per your requirements, i.e. when first activating the Home button, the JFileChooser uses the path stored in the [System] property user.home and the second time the button is activated, the path is the .jpilot subdirectory of user.home. The third time that the Home button is activated, the path returns to user.home and so on.
Note that this code is not production quality. Think of it as a POC.
class CustomFileSystemView extends FileSystemView {
    private static final String newFolderString = UIManager.getString("FileChooser.win32.newFolder");
    private static final String newFolderNextString = UIManager.getString("FileChooser.win32.newFolder.subsequent");

    private boolean  toggled;

    public Boolean isTraversable(File f) {
        return Boolean.valueOf(isFileSystemRoot(f) || isComputerNode(f) || f.isDirectory());
    }

    public File getChild(File parent, String fileName) {
        if (fileName.startsWith("\\")
            && !fileName.startsWith("\\\\")
            && isFileSystem(parent)) {

            //Path is relative to the root of parent's drive
            String path = parent.getAbsolutePath();
            if (path.length() >= 2
                && path.charAt(1) == ':'
                && Character.isLetter(path.charAt(0))) {

                return createFileObject(path.substring(0, 2) + fileName);
            }
        }
        return super.getChild(parent, fileName);
    }

    public String getSystemTypeDescription(File f) {
        if (f == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return f.getName();
    }

    public File getHomeDirectory() {
        String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
        if (toggled) {
            home += File.separator + ".jpilot";
        }
        toggled = !toggled;
        return new File(home);
    }

    public File createNewFolder(File containingDir) throws IOException {
        if(containingDir == null) {
            throw new IOException("Containing directory is null:");
        }
        // Using NT's default folder name
        File newFolder = createFileObject(containingDir, newFolderString);
        int i = 2;
        while (newFolder.exists() && i < 100) {
            newFolder = createFileObject(containingDir, MessageFormat.format(
                newFolderNextString, i));
            i++;
        }

        if(newFolder.exists()) {
            throw new IOException("Directory already exists:" + newFolder.getAbsolutePath());
        } else {
            if(!newFolder.mkdirs()) {
                throw new IOException(newFolder.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        return newFolder;
    }

    public boolean isDrive(File dir) {
        return isFileSystemRoot(dir);
    }

    public File createFileObject(String path) {
        // Check for missing backslash after drive letter such as "C:" or "C:filename"
        if (path.length() >= 2 && path.charAt(1) == ':' && Character.isLetter(path.charAt(0))) {
            if (path.length() == 2) {
                path += "\\";
            } else if (path.charAt(2) != '\\') {
                path = path.substring(0, 2) + "\\" + path.substring(2);
            }
        }
        return super.createFileObject(path);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial") // anonymous class
    protected File createFileSystemRoot(File f) {
        // Problem: Removable drives on Windows return false on f.exists()
        // Workaround: Override exists() to always return true.
        return new File(f.getAbsolutePath()) {
            public boolean exists() {
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
}

In order for JFileChooser to use my CustomFileSystemView class, I call method setFileSystemView, as demonstrated below:
fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setFileSystemView(new CustomFileSystemView());


As you can see in my edit above, in my case it is UnixFileSystemView. I have a little pain, coding such a derived FileSystemView. One reason is, that it would not be "portable". But thanks for the great approach.

Isn't there a way to access the ActionListener of the internal Home button? Then I could use the more simple code of the other answer of @prasad_.

With the following code I could examine the component hierarchy:
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.list();

Result:
javax.swing.JFileChooser[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder@4534e435,flags=320,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,approveButtonText=,currentDirectory=/home/ich,dialogTitle=,dialogType=OPEN_DIALOG,fileSelectionMode=FILES_ONLY,returnValue=ERROR_OPTION,selectedFile=,useFileHiding=true]
 javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
  javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.BoxLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
   javax.swing.JButton[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@374290f,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=sun.swing.ImageIconUIResource@4d1d8b03,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=null,defaultCapable=true]
   javax.swing.Box$Filler[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=5,height=1],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=5,height=1],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=5,height=1]]
   javax.swing.JButton[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@374290f,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=sun.swing.ImageIconUIResource@6820ad98,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]
   javax.swing.Box$Filler[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=5,height=1],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=5,height=1],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=5,height=1]]
   javax.swing.JButton[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@374290f,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=sun.swing.ImageIconUIResource@1ed5f5f6,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=null,defaultCapable=true]
   javax.swing.Box$Filler[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=5,height=1],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=5,height=1],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=5,height=1]]
   javax.swing.JToggleButton[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@2ed9e4bf,flags=360,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalIconFactory$FileChooserListViewIcon@5e8f99fe,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=false,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=]
   javax.swing.JToggleButton[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@2ed9e4bf,flags=360,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalIconFactory$FileChooserDetailViewIcon@4378c091,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=false,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=]
  javax.swing.JLabel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=8388992,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$1[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxUI$MetalComboBoxLayoutManager,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=328,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isEditable=false,lightWeightPopupEnabled=true,maximumRowCount=8,selectedItemReminder=/home/ich],text=Suchen in:,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]
  javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$1[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxUI$MetalComboBoxLayoutManager,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=328,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isEditable=false,lightWeightPopupEnabled=true,maximumRowCount=8,selectedItemReminder=/home/ich]
   javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxButton[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@374290f,flags=12583208,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=1,bottom=1,right=3],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=false,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]
   javax.swing.CellRendererPane[,0,0,0x0,invalid,hidden]
 javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
 sun.swing.FilePane[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=265,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=405,height=135]]
  javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=8388617,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
   javax.swing.JScrollPane[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout$UIResource,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders$ScrollPaneBorder@5843fcbe,flags=8388936,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,columnHeader=,horizontalScrollBar=javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=12583240,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,blockIncrement=10,orientation=HORIZONTAL,unitIncrement=1],horizontalScrollBarPolicy=HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,lowerLeft=,lowerRight=,rowHeader=,upperLeft=,upperRight=,verticalScrollBar=javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=12583240,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,blockIncrement=10,orientation=VERTICAL,unitIncrement=1],verticalScrollBarPolicy=VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,viewport=javax.swing.JViewport[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.ViewportLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=8388616,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isViewSizeSet=false,lastPaintPosition=,scrollUnderway=false],viewportBorder=]
    javax.swing.JViewport[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.ViewportLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=8388616,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isViewSizeSet=false,lastPaintPosition=,scrollUnderway=false]
     sun.swing.FilePane$4[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=41943336,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,fixedCellHeight=-1,fixedCellWidth=-1,horizontalScrollIncrement=-1,selectionBackground=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],selectionForeground=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],visibleRowCount=0,layoutOrientation=1]
      javax.swing.CellRendererPane[,0,0,0x0,invalid,hidden]
    javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=12583240,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,blockIncrement=10,orientation=VERTICAL,unitIncrement=1]
     javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollButton[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@374290f,flags=12583208,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]
     javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollButton[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@374290f,flags=12583208,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]
    javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=12583240,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,blockIncrement=10,orientation=HORIZONTAL,unitIncrement=1]
     javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollButton[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@374290f,flags=12583208,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]
     javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollButton[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@374290f,flags=12583208,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]
 javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.BoxLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
  javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.BoxLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
   javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$AlignedLabel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=8388992,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$3[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@632c2f51,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],columns=35,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING],text=Dateiname:,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]
   javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$3[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@632c2f51,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],columns=35,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING]
  javax.swing.Box$Filler[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=1,height=5],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=1,height=5],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=1,height=5]]
  javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.BoxLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
   javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$AlignedLabel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=8388992,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=javax.swing.JComboBox[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxUI$MetalComboBoxLayoutManager,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=328,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isEditable=false,lightWeightPopupEnabled=true,maximumRowCount=8,selectedItemReminder=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI$AcceptAllFileFilter@de4953],text=Dateityp:,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]
   javax.swing.JComboBox[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxUI$MetalComboBoxLayoutManager,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=328,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isEditable=false,lightWeightPopupEnabled=true,maximumRowCount=8,selectedItemReminder=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI$AcceptAllFileFilter@de4953]
    javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxButton[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@374290f,flags=12583208,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=1,bottom=1,right=3],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=false,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]
    javax.swing.CellRendererPane[,0,0,0x0,invalid,hidden]
  javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$ButtonAreaLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
   javax.swing.JButton[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@374290f,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=Öffnen,defaultCapable=true]
   javax.swing.JButton[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@374290f,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=Abbrechen,defaultCapable=true]

So the very smart solution is:
static final File JPILOT_DIR = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".jpilot");
static final File TESTDATA_DIR = new File("TestData", "in");
[.....]
  JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
  JButton customBtn = new JButton(".jpilot / TestData");
  customBtn.addActionListener(e -> {
    fc.setCurrentDirectory(
        fc.getCurrentDirectory() == JPILOT_DIR ? TESTDATA_DIR : JPILOT_DIR);
  });
  if (fc.getComponents()[fc.getComponentCount()-1] instanceof Container bottom)
    if (bottom.getComponents()[bottom.getComponentCount()-1] instanceof Container buttonPanel)
      buttonPanel.add(customBtn, 0);

  fc.showOpenDialog(null);

I discarded my initial idea of using the "Home" button, but that would also be simple with that technique and using the examination of this answer.
A probable more robust variant – depending on future changes inside JFileChooser – is:
private static JComponent findLastPanel(JComponent parent) {
  for (int i = parent.getComponentCount(); i-- > 0 ; )
    if (parent.getComponents()[i] instanceof JPanel last)
      return findLastPanel(last);
  return parent;
}
[.....]
  JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
  findLastPanel(fc).add(customBtn, 0);



Messing around with the internal layout of the JFileChooser class by using getComponents() and "guessing" the correct index to find the correct JPanel feels hackish and is not very robust. If the internal layout is changed or a different layout is used for a different OS this solution won't work anymore.

@Progman Your arguments samely apply more or less on the other posted solutions.
